# Everytime I've tried to make a bootable usb stick with Ubuntu 15.04 or later I get this error when I try to boot from it

Tags: boot, usb, 15.04

This is the error message:

```
Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path gfxboot.c32: not aCOM32R image.
```

I've tried Ubuntu 15.04, 15.10 beta 2 and Kubuntu 15.04 beta 2 and they all give me this error message. Ubuntu 14.10 boots ok from the same stick.

I like to try using bootable usb sticks to try it out...

I have a HP Pavillion a1000 w/2GB ram. AMD 64bit uprocessor.

Comment: how did you created the usb boot ?

Comment: When creating a bootable USB of ubuntu, I recommend using ubuntu's built-in Disk Image Creator. It's the only sure-to-work method I know of that doesn't leave any broken pieces behind. Have you tried making the LiveUSB with that?

Comment: No, I've only used Startup Disk Creator so far.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in ubuntu, it shipped with some faulty default parameters. Try pressing "tab" when you see this error, it will show you different boot options. Type the name of the option you want and press enter. Usually typing "live" and pressing enter works.

https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/ubuntu/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb/

Comment: ok, I've tried this but it booted up into Lubuntu. I'm  waiting until 16.04 comes out then reformatting my harddrive and getting rid of everything.

Comment: Ok, I had Lubuntu 15.10 on that flashdrive. Redid it with Ubuntu 15.10 and was successful in booting right in. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, and glad your problem is solved. Please accept the answer if it was useful.